# Visual Studio não reconhece CSS

Tags: css, visual-studio

Peguei um template de Bootstrap pronto, porém o Visual Studio 2019 não está reconhecendo algumas propriedades.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E não está renderizando a aplicação.

Comment: Vc está usando o arquivo minificado?

Comment: Estão no mesmo Path?

Comment: não me parece que não está reconhecendo, mas sim que vc está usando como target o CSS 4.0, e essas extensions "-webkit" não são suportadas, me parece correto. Mude para CSS 3.0 e deve sumir esses warnings

Comment: estou usando o bootstrap.css, sim mesmo path

Comment: Ricardo, sabe por onde acesso essa opção no 2019 ? Procurei mas não achei :(